# Fade out "add to cart" success message in Magento

Tags: javascript, php, mobile, e-commerce, magento2

The client wants to fadeout the success message after few seconds by clicking add to cart button.

I have made a change in `addCartSuccessMessage.phtml` file like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template $block */
?>

<?= $block->escapeHtml(__(
    'You added %1 to your <a href="%2">shopping cart</a>.',
    $block->getData('product_name'),
    $block->getData('cart_url')
), ['a']);

?>
<script type="text/javascript">

    require(['jquery'], function($){
        $(".message.success").fadeOut(7000);

    });
</script>
```

Now the problem is if I open up the site on mobile, the notification shows up only one time and after that no matter how many times I click on the "add to cart" button, the success message wont show up. It shows up again only if I refresh the page

Comment: I believe the issue is that once you call fadeOut(), the message is hidden. At some point you need the message to be visible again. Try: `$(".message.success").show().fadeOut(7000);`

Comment: it worked for desktop but for mobile view it did not work